# Preserving lower/upper bound for Range data type

Tags: sql, postgresql, range, date-range, sqldatatypes

Take the following query as an example

```
WITH dummy(x) AS (
    SELECT '[2018-12-01, 2019-01-15]'::daterange
)
SELECT lower(x), upper(x) FROM dummy
```

This gives

```
   lower    |   upper
------------+------------
 2018-12-01 | 2019-01-16
```

The upper bound of the inserted literal is `2019-01-15`, but when I retrieve it, the upper bound magically becomes `2019-01-16`. How can I preserve the original bounds?

Comment: You can't - [this is documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE) "*The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, `[)`*"

Comment: All you can do is test whether the upper bounds is inclusive or not `SELECT upper_inc('[2018-12-01, 2019-01-15]'::daterange); f`

Answer (score 0):

As the top comment wisely pointed out, [the document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE) says

> The built-in range types `int4range`, `int8range`, and `daterange` all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, `[)`.

which means it's impossible to preserve the original bounds if the data are store in a `Range`. However, if you don't mind altering the schema, you can store the bounds as-is and have PostgreSQL generate a `Range` for you.

```sql
create table foo (
    ...

    begin_date date      not null,
    end_date   date      not null,
    period     daterange not null generated always as ( daterange(begin_date, end_date, '[]') ) stored,

    ...
)
```

This way `begin_date` and `end_date` would faithfully store their original value and the table would remain backward-compatible thanks to the generated `Range` column.